# как сохранять расположение новых элементов jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так чтобы новые блоки сохранялись у клиента после перезагрузки страницы

```
<input id="pts" />
<a href="#" class="pts">UPDATE</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function(){
    $('a.pts').click(function(){
        var obj=this;
        var inputPts=$('input').val();
        $(document.body).append("<br>"+ inputPts);
    });
})
```

Comment: Сохранять их (где? на клиенте? на сервере?) и воссоздавать во время загрузки страницы.

Comment: сохранялись на клиенте

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Igor оформите свой комментарий как ответ